# Move down titoletto in frontespizio

Tags: frontespizio

I'm writing my italian dissertation and using frontespizio package for my frontespiece.

This is my piece of code regarding this part:

```
\begin{frontespizio}
\Istituzione{UNIVERSITA' DEGLI STUDI DI CITTA "QUALSIASI" }
\Dipartimento{Science and Tecnology}
\Corso[Laurea]{Informatica}
\Annoaccademico{2015--2016}
\Titoletto{Tesi di Laurea}
\Titolo{Titolo della tesi}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontsmallfont}[1]{\small Matr.}}
\Candidato[0123456789]{Mario Rossi}
\Relatore{Prof. Giuseppe Verdi}
\Margini{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}
\Filigrana[height=4cm,before=2.6,after=8.8]{images/ubuntu-logo}
\Punteggiatura{}
\end{frontespizio}
```

The output is this image.
[image: frontespizio output]

What I need now is that the 'titoletto' (Tesi di Laurea) should go under the logo and just before the dissertation title, that is the 'titolo' part, and not appear on the logo.

How can I solve it using this package? Or do I need to use another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the “titoletto” part of the title:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[swapnames]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontespizio}
\begin{Preambolo*}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname front@docand\endcsname
  {Matricola}{Matr.\ }{}{}
\end{Preambolo*}
\Istituzione{UNIVERSIT\`A DEGLI STUDI DI CITT\`A ``QUALSIASI''}
\Dipartimento{Science and Tecnology}
\Corso[Laurea]{Informatica}
\Annoaccademico{2015--2016}
%\Titoletto{Tesi di Laurea}
\Titolo{{\frontpretitlefont Tesi di laurea\\[1ex]}Titolo della tesi}
\Candidato[0123456789]{Mario Rossi}
\Relatore{Prof. Giuseppe Verdi}
\Margini{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}
\Filigrana[height=4cm,before=2.6,after=8.8]{duck}
\Punteggiatura{}
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

I added a better way for changing “Matricola” into “Matr.”

[image]

Comment: may I use this package even if I'm writing in British English `\usepackage[british]{babel}`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, of course, provided you replace all fixed parts (except for “Matricola” everything is changeable). You don't need `babel`.

Comment: I'm writing in English but I'm Italian, and my frontespizio is in Italian, hence I don't even have to change anything, thank you very much!

Comment: @egreg, is there a way to use a normal font, and not bold?

Comment: @Franktrt Look at the definitions for the fonts in the manual and change them in `Preambolo*`

Comment: @egreg, I have used it to change them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way around this is to manually add some vertical space before the line you want to move down. Optionally insert some negative vertical space afterwards to prevent the following items from shifting down as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontespizio}
\Istituzione{UNIVERSITA' DEGLI STUDI DI CITTA "QUALSIASI" }
\Dipartimento{Science and Tecnology}
\Corso[Laurea]{Informatica}
\Annoaccademico{2015--2016}
\Titoletto{\vspace{4cm}Tesi di Laurea\vspace{-4cm}}
\Titolo{Titolo della tesi}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\frontsmallfont}[1]{\small Matr.}}
\Candidato[0123456789]{Mario Rossi}
\Relatore{Prof. Giuseppe Verdi}
\Margini{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}
\Filigrana[height=4cm,before=2.6,after=8.8]{save-icon}
\Punteggiatura{}
\end{frontespizio}
\end{document}
```

Result (with the first random image I could find...):

[image]

The *correct way* would be to investigate the options or source code of `frontespizio`. Maybe @egreg can assist you here (he is the author of the package).

Comment: I've tried your solution and it is good form me. Anyway I accepted the solution provided by @egreg because I finally used it and I changed the font with some of his commands. Thanks for your help